# Compare two same images with different orientation in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am comparing two same images with different orientations. Comparing results says that these images are different, But I want to get results in same.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: are you using UIImagePNGRepresentation for comparing?

Comment: yes am using UIImagePNGRepresentation

this is my code : NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(getImage1); NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(getImage2);

Answer (score 0):

yes am using UIImagePNGRepresentation

this is my code :
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(getImage1);
    NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(getImage2);